# How to store the contents of a line in vim to a register

Tags: vim

new to vim (only about 2 days), and was wondering if I could take a file, eg:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
```

and use some command to store the contents of the line the cursor is on into the @a register?

as an example, if i was on line 3 and ran some command, then "this is line 3" would be in the @a register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To yank the current line to the `a` register

```
"aY
```

You can inspect what's in all of the registers with

```
:reg
```